# Manipulating strings with Swift

Tags: xcode, macos, swift2

I am trying to divide a String in Swift. I have the following string

`Program - /path/to/file.doc`

I want to get three informations out of this string
`Program`
`/path/to/file.doc`
`file.doc`

I began with the following solution

```
var str = "Program - /path/to/file.doc"
let indi = str.rangeOfString("-")?.startIndex 
let subString = str.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: str.startIndex, end: indi!))
let subString2 = str.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: indi!, end: str.endIndex))
```

This gives me the results 
`"Program "`and
`"- /path/to/file.doc"`

But how can I get `file.doc` after the last `/`?

How Can i increase/decrease and range index to avoid blank spaces?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't know Swift to answer your question, but In objective-c, I would first get an array from that string using `componentsSeparatedByString:@" - "`. Then, element 0 is your name and 1 is the path. Use `[[NSURL urlWithString:[array lastObject]] lastPathComponent]` to get that filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sidyll's suggestion is correct, it's a very common practice to get components of Unix path by converting it to NSURL. You may want to write something like this:

```
var str = "Program - /path/to/file.doc"
if let indi = str.rangeOfString(" - ")?.startIndex {
    let subString = str.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: str.startIndex, end: indi))
    let subString2 = str.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: indi, end: str.endIndex))
    let fileName = NSURL(string: subString2).lastPathComponent()
}
```

I strongly suggest you don't do force unwrap like this. Consider situation if this code will work with string without a particular pattern, for example empty string. Correct, runtime error.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for sending this code. And indeed important suggestions regarding the format and safety.

Comment: Minor simplification (from your original code): You don't need `Range<String.Index>(start: x, end: y)`. All of that is equivalent to `x..<y`.